# Dart/Flutter stream generator stops when no subscriber

Tags: dart, stream, generator

I'm trying out Dart/Flutter's Stream function.

Is there any way to kickstart the stream generator without any subscriber? It works when I subscribe to it yet the generator stops right away after last subscriber has left. I want it to keep generating (in this case so that _count can keep incrementing over time even when no subscriber).

I'm trying to mimic async data appearing in a stream (that Future.delayed of 3 sec is just slowing it down) hence using Stream.periodic doesn't quite cut it.

```
void main() {
  Stream<int> generateStream() async*{
    int _count = 0;
    while (true) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
      print(_count);
      yield _count++;
    }
  }

  generateStream();
}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [StreamController](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-async/StreamController-class.html) to publish results to its `stream` property.

Keep in mind, that normal Streams accept only one subscriber in their lifetime and you need to `broadcast` StreamControllers if you plan to (re-)subscribe multiple times.

Here is an example:

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() async {
  StreamController<int> ctrl = StreamController<int>.broadcast();
  Stream<int> stream = ctrl.stream;

  // a handle to manage the current subscription
  StreamSubscription<int> sub;

  for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    // wait for 0.2s
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200));

    // add a value to the controller
    ctrl.add(i);

    if (i == 10) {
      // add listener
      sub = stream.listen(listener);
    }
    else if (i == 20) {
      // cancel sub after 4 seconds
      sub.cancel();
    }
    if (i == 30) {
      // resub after 6 seconds
      sub = stream.listen(listener);
    }
  }

  ctrl.close();
}


void listener(int value) {
  print(value);
}
```

There are also other classes for similar purposes, like [BehaviorSubject](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/BehaviorSubject-class.html), [PublishSUbject](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/PublishSubject-class.html) and [ReplaySubject](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/ReplaySubject-class.html).

Comment: Thanks for answering. It works. I guess I was looking at the wrong place to begin with.